# how to hidden/canceled notification in android(4.0+)

Tags: android, android-service

I want to build a service that hide all notification in android 4.0+

I found this code :

```
NotificationListenerService.cancelNotification(String pkg, String tag, int id);
```

but this service just worked on android 4.3+

can anyone help me?

Comment: What you want was not supported on Android prior to the introduction of `NotificationListenerService`.

Comment: "i want my service support all the version of android" -- then you will be disappointed. "i think, i should be use notification manager" -- `NotificationManager` only works with your own notifications. You have no means, outside of `NotificationListenerService` or custom ROMs, to alter or remove the notifications of other apps. "notificationManager.cancel(int id)" -- that is for **your own app's notification**, for which you should already know the ID.

Comment: @CommonsWare so how can i hidden all notification? just by NotificationListenerService? how?

Comment: "so how can i hidden all notification? just by NotificationListenerService?" -- I know of no other way, and there should not be another way outside of flaws. "how?" -- I see [a `cancelAllNotifications()` method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html#cancelAllNotifications%28%29) that looks promising.

Comment: @CommonsWare even for android 4.4 ?!! there is'nt any way?!!